# Error in Shiny App which includes data.table function

Tags: r, shiny, data.table

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(
  Timestamp =as.POSIXct(c(1689769414, 1689769426, 
                          1689769438, 1689769450, 1689769462, 1689769474, 1689769486, 1689769499, 
                          1689769511, 1689769523, 1689769534, 1689769547, 1689769559, 1689769570, 
                          1689769583, 1689769595, 1689769607, 1689769618, 1689769630, 1689769642, 
                          1689769654, 1689769666, 1689769678, 1689769690, 1689769703, 1689769714, 
                          1689769726, 1689769739, 1689769750, 1689769763, 1689769774, 1689769786, 
                          1689769799, 1689769810, 1689769823, 1689769835, 1689769847, 1689769860, 
                          1689769871, 1689769884, 1689769895, 1689769907, 1689769919, 1689769931, 
                          1689769944, 1689769956, 1689769968, 1689769982, 1689769995, 1689770021, 
                          1689770035, 1689770047, 1689770059, 1689770072, 1689770083, 1689770096, 
                          1689770107, 1689770119, 1689770132, 1689770143, 1689770155, 1689770168, 
                          1689770181, 1689770197, 1689770208, 1689770221, 1689770233, 1689770246, 
                          1689770257, 1689770270, 1689770282, 1689770293, 1689770306, 1689770318, 
                          1689770329, 1689770342, 1689770354, 1689770384, 1689770395, 1689770407, 
                          1689770420, 1689770432, 1689770444, 1689770456, 1689770469, 1689770482, 
                          1689770493, 1689770505, 1689770517, 1689770530, 1689770542, 1689770555, 
                          1689770568, 1689770579, 1689770591, 1689770603, 1689770615, 1689770628, 
                          1689770640, 1689770652
  )),
  Heat_Capacity = c(
    5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 7, 6.5, 6, 
    5.5, 5, 4.5, 4, 3.5, 3, 2.5, 2, 1.5, 1, 0.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 1.5, 
    2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 6.96, 6.46, 5.96, 
    5.46, 4.96, 4.46, 3.96, 3.46, 2.96, 2.46, 1.92, 1.42, 0.83, 0.29, 
    0.79, 1.33, 1.88, 2.38, 2.88, 3.38, 3.88, 4.38, 4.88, 5.38, 5.88, 
    6.38, 6.92, 7.42, 6.92, 6.42, 5.92, 5.38, 4.88, 4.38, 3.88, 3.38, 
    2.88, 2.38, 1.88, 1.38, 0.88, 0.38, 0.88, 1.38, 1.88, 2.42, 2.92, 
    3.42, 3.92, 4.46, 4.96, 5.46, 5.96, 6.46, 6.96, 7.46, 6.96, 6.46, 
    5.96, 5.46, 4.96, 4.46, 3.96, 3.46, 2.96
  )
)
```

I have this shiny App which plots line chart based on  the above data :
Here some data manipulation on the datframe is done using data.table()

```
library(shiny)
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

    ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(
          
          plotlyOutput("plot")
        )
      )
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
      
      
    
    #'*For Graph*'
      
      output$plot <- renderPlotly({
        
        
        one <- df
        
        date_range <- one[,base::round(range(`Timestamp`)+c(-60*60, 60*60), unit="hours")]
        df_regular <- data.table::data.table(`Timestamp` = do.call(seq, c(as.list(date_range), "15 min")))
        one_ui <- one[df_regular, ,on = "`Timestamp`", roll = +15*60, nomatch=NULL]
    
        
        
        one_graph <- one_ui%>% 
          ggplot(aes(x = .[[1]], y = .[[2]])) +
          geom_line()
        
        
        ggplotly(one_graph)
      })
    }
    
    shinyApp( ui,  server)
```

When I try to run the app I keep getting the **error**:

> unused argument (unit = "hours")

but when I try to run it out without the Shiny. It works fine

Comment: Hm. When I convert your `data.frame` `df` to a `data.table` using `df <- data.table(df)` your code works fine.

Comment: So you are getting a line chart as output in the Shiny App right?

Comment: @stefan is it due to any masking problem?

Comment: From your error it sounds a bit like so. Have you already tried running your example code in a fresh R session?

Comment: I did but it's same error again

Comment: @stefan Even when I try to run  the code in  Rstudio of posit cloud its the same error

Comment: Weird. No clue what might be the issue. Just to make sure: You added `df <- data.table(df)` to your code as I did?

Comment: No I didn't. I think that's why.

In my old code :  `one <- df`